# Pre Requisites for DBMS_XMLDOM

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have written a PL/SQL block that writes an XML file into DB directory

When I execute the block, I face an issue :

```
identifier 'DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDOCUMENT' must be declared
```

What are the prerequisites to work with `dbms_xmldom`?

Database version is 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: When I try to grant execute on dbms_xmldom, it throws that object does not exist. Is this object implicilty available in DB ?

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_XMLDOM requires:

1. **Installation of Oracle XML Database.**  Check for the installation with this SQL: `select * from dba_registry where comp_id = 'XDB';`.  It's difficult to say why it would not be installed, DBAs tend to have different opinions on installing optional components.  But in this case, it doesn't cost any money, you need it, and I believe XDB will be required in a future release anyway.  You'll need to get a DBA involved to install the option.
2. **Privileges to execute the package.**  `select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'DBMS_XMLDOM';` should show EXECUTE granted to PUBLIC.  There have been security concerns with some Oracle packages, especially the XML ones.  I'm not sure whether these security worries apply anymore, but once a package is on a blacklist it tends to stay there.  Someone with SYSDBA will need to run `grant execute on sys.dbms_xmldom to public;` or to your specific user or role.

By default this package is available to all users.  Someone must have intentionally removed the ability to use it.